# function scrollPage() does not work on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function in javascript that needs to scroll the page up and down until the user presses a button to disable it. Here is my current function:

```
var scrollDirection = 1;
function scrollPage() {
  if (isScrollMode) {
    window.scrollBy(0, scrollDirection); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
    scrolldelay = setTimeout('scrollPage()', 50); // scrolls every 50 milliseconds
    if (window.pageYOffset == 0) {
      scrollDirection = 1;
    } else if (window.pageYOffset == document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight) {
      scrollDirection = -1;
    }
  }
}
```

So far this method works on a computer, however, when I tested this function on my google chrome web browser on my phone, it only went down and not up. Once it reaches the end of the page, it stays there. Can anyone tell me why? I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `window.pageYOffset` return a float, in my case `78.4000015258789`and `document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight` return a integer, in my case `79`.
Then, `(78.4000015258789 == 79) = false`

What you can change is to add one to `window.pageYOffset`to get `79.4` and check if `window.pageYOffset > (document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight)`

Here is the edited code (must be working) :

```js
var scrollspeed = 10;
var scrollDirection = scrollspeed;
function scrollPage() {
  if (isScrollMode) {
    window.scrollBy(0, scrollDirection); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
    scrolldelay = setTimeout("scrollPage()", 50); // scrolls every 50 milliseconds
    if (window.pageYOffset == 0) {
      scrollDirection = scrollspeed;
    } else if (
      window.pageYOffset + 1 >
      document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight
    ) {
      //window.pageYOffset return a float scroll y value, for exemple in my case 78.4000015258789;
      //We add +1 to obtain 79.4
      //(document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight) return a interger of 79
      scrollDirection = -scrollspeed;
    }
  }
}
let isScrollMode = true;
scrollPage();
```

```html
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
```

Comment: Awesome job. I need to update my website and test, but thanks for the help! I'll let you know if it works!